# Source address in iptables Masquerade/NAT

Tags: iptables, openvpn

I'm trying to install OpenVpn on a remote Ubuntu 20 server and am following this [tut](https://linuxconfig.org/openvpn-setup-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux). I'm able to step through it but cannot determine where this source address is in its example:

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

The table, Appending, outgoing interface I have figured out. But I want to understand what the source addy is supposed to be. If it was the IP addy of the eth0 port, then it would make sense to be a single addy. But this is a range. Perhaps it's a white list of allowed client addy's? Reading other posts here don't include a source address/range but those posts may not be setting up a private VPN server.
Thx for reading.

Comment: MASQUERADE is the source address of the outgoing interface.  As you wrote it right now traffic heading from internal 10.8.0.0/24 to any destination via eth0 as the exfil interface will masquerade as the IP address of eth0.

Comment: Thank you, if --source is essentially the same as the IP addy of eth0, would this example work with a single IP addy of the remote server running OpenVpn? This example using a range of IP addy's for its source is throwing me.

Comment: I'll write up a diagram and provide an example of things with my VPN configs as to how this works.  Especially with a server that has multiple exfil IPs then it gets complicated.  Give me some time thoughu.